# System doesnt recognize python system

Tags: python, file, system

I am trying to run a python file. I ve installed python 2.7.4. My code in .py file is just

```
import os 
print('hellp world')
```

However I am receiving as a message:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'python', u'-u', u'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\main.py']]
[dir:  C:\Users\...\Desktop]
[path: C:\Program Files.. ... ... ..., C:\Python27]
[Finished]
```

Any idea why the system doensnt recognize python file? In ENV path I have set the path of python.exe and in command prompt I ve tried the command python and I got the error python is not recognized as internal or external command.

Comment: it fails to **find** it, not **recognize**. Check your paths

Comment: How are you trying to run your file? From IDLE?

Comment: From sublime. When I run in python command prompt just python I am getting python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe python is not in your `%PATH%`?

Quoting the python documentation

> Besides using the automatically created start menu entry for the Python interpreter, you might want to start Python in the DOS prompt. To make this work, you need to set your %PATH% environment variable to include the directory of your Python distribution, delimited by a semicolon from other entries. An example variable could look like this (assuming the first two entries are Windows’ default):
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Python27
>
> Typing python on your command prompt will now fire up the Python interpreter. Thus, you can also  execute your scripts with command line options, see Command line documentation.

Comment: If you see the error, the enviroment path includes c:\python27.